# tcsh & stat: comparing files' modification times in script

Tags: comparison, tcsh, stat

I wrote a tcsh script [warning, I am fairly new to tcsh!] that checks the extension of the input file, if it has read permissions, and also outputs a pdf version from its .tex input file.

My next step is wanting to make the program **exit if the modification time of the generated, pdf, file is more recent than the input file's modification time**.

I saw that I could resort to **stat** and thought of storing the modification times from stat into variables.

```
#$1 is the name of the .tex file, like sample.tex
set mtime_pdf = `echo stat -c %Y $1:t:r.pdf` 
set mtime_tex = `echo stat -C %Y $1`
```

Now how do I go about comparing them? **I want to be able to do something like** (this is more pseudo-code like)

```
if ( $mtime_pdf < $mtime_tex ) then
      echo "too new!"
      exit 2
```

Thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: [don't use tcsh for scripting...](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)

Comment: @shx2 Oh, I agree! But I didn't have a choice on this project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say but `stat -c %Y` points towards Linux. The problem with `stat` is that its arguments aren't very portable. A more portable way of doing file compares is using `find`.

Your `set` commands should lose the `echo`.

All in all here is an example that demonstrates both approaches:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

if ( $#argv < 2 ) then
    echo "Usage: $0 <file> <file>"
    exit 2
endif

set t1=`stat -c '%Y' $1`
set t2=`stat -c '%Y' $2`
echo "$1 is $t1 seconds old"
echo "$2 is $t2 seconds old"

if ( $t1 < $t2 ) then
    echo "$1 is older as $2"
else
    echo "$1 is newer or the same age as $2"
endif

if { find $1 -newer $2 } then
    echo "$1 was modified after or at the same time as $2"
else
    echo "$1 was modified before as $2"
endif

if { find $1 -cnewer $2 } then
    echo "$1 was created after or at the same time as $2"
else
    echo "$1 was created before $2"
endif
```

Comment: My test shows that the return code of `find -newer` maybe always 0, which may pass the if checking anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply use tcsh's file inquiry operators, something like:

```
if ( ( -M file1 ) >= ( -M file2 ) ) then
    echo 'file 1 newer'
else
    echo 'file 2 newer'
endif
```

Seems simpler than using stat.

Regards